# Lightweight database-like library for storing key-value pairs

Tags: java, database, hashmap

What is the best way of storing key-value pairs of Strings in a file in Java, that is scalable (can work with a large number of pairs, i.e. doesn't read or write entire file on access), but is as lightweight as possible?

I am asking this because even the lightest database libraries, like SQLite and H2 seem like an overkill for this purpose, and are even impossible to use for ME programs (although I would need this mainly for SE programs for now).

Comment: The "best" way will depend on factors such as the read/write pattern or the total size of data, as well as what you mean by "lightweight".   Do you care about disk overhead? Size of library? Memory footprint? Can you add some clarification?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! Read speed would be more important than write, although both should be fast. By lightweight I mean small library, disk overhead is not so important, although it shouldn't be too large (if data is 50kb, file shouldn't be more than 100kb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Oracle BerkeleyDB java edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index-093405.html) allows you to store key-value objects, it is simple to use and administer, and up-scalable to heaven (or so). At 820k is not that big.

But if you are thinking about down scaling to j2me, you may try [TinySQL](http://www.jepstone.net/tinySQL/)

Pros:

- It is small (93k!)
- It is embeddable
- It uses DBF or text files files to store data, so they are easy
  to read.

Cons:

- It is an old unmaintained project
- It is not designed to work in j2me, but since it can work in JDK 1.1.8 it won't be hard to make it work in j2me. Of course you will have to change some code from using RandomAccessFile to FileConnection and stuff like that, but at least you wont need to mess with generics related code.
- It is not very fast, because it does not use indexes, so you need to try and see if it is fits your needs
- It is not feature complete, just gives you a small subset of SQL

Answer (score 0):

There are some good ideas  [**in this SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268885/how-to-store-key-value-pairs-in-a-file-that-will-be-stored-in-internal-memory-in). My own inclination would be to use noSQL or similar, while that discussion is more centered on hashmap. Either will do, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

For a static set of key-value pairs, Dan Bernstein's [cdb](http://cr.yp.to/cdb.html) comes to mind.  To quote from the cdb description:

> cdb is a fast, reliable, simple package for creating and reading constant databases. Its database structure provides several features:
>
> - Fast lookups: A successful lookup in a large database normally takes just two disk accesses. An unsuccessful lookup takes only one.
> - Low overhead: A database uses 2048 bytes, plus 24 bytes per record, plus the space for keys and data.
> - No random limits: cdb can handle any database up to 4 gigabytes. There are no other restrictions; records don't even have to fit into memory. Databases are stored in a machine-independent format.
> - Fast atomic database replacement: cdbmake can rewrite an entire database two orders of magnitude faster than other hashing packages.
> - Fast database dumps: cdbdump prints the contents of a database in cdbmake-compatible format.
>
> cdb is designed to be used in mission-critical applications like e-mail. Database replacement is safe against system crashes. Readers don't have to pause during a rewrite.

It appears there is a Java implementation available at http://www.strangegizmo.com/products/sg-cdb/ with a BSD license.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious initial thoughts are to use Properties as these are streamed but they are ultimately fully loaded. You also couldn't partially read a buffered set.

With that in mind, you could see this additional other SO response. This refers to navigating (albeit imperfectly) around a stream so that you could reposition your read:

[changing the index positioning in InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474911/changing-the-index-positioning-in-inputstream)

With a separate index (say by initial character) you could intelligently reposition the cursor in the stream, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

[Chronicle Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map) is a modern off-heap key-value store for Java. If could be (optionally) persisted to disk, acting like an eventually-consistent database. Chronicle Map features

- Queries which are faster than 1 us, in some use-cases as fast as 100 ns (see [comparison with other similar libraries for Java](http://jetbrains.github.io/xodus/#benchmarks)).
- Perfect scalability for processing from multiple threads and even processes, thanks to segmented shared-nothing design and multi-level locks, allowing multiple operations to access the same data concurrently.
- Very low overhead per entry, less than 20 bytes / entry [is achievable](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/blob/4bcdcdb8cee4c87a677e9ee71fbf6d481b0d9277/src/test/java/net/openhft/chronicle/map/MarkTest.java).